# Inference about system causality

Tags: signal, signal-processing

This is follow-up question to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79824/meaning-of-causal-signal/79826?noredirect=1#79826).

For the inferences made below(may be wrong),
let $$h[n]=impulse\hspace{1.5mm} response\hspace{1.5mm} of\hspace{1.5mm} the\hspace{1.5mm} LTI\hspace{1.5mm} system$$

$$x[n]=input\hspace{1.5mm} signal\hspace{1.5mm} to\hspace{1.5mm} the\hspace{1.5mm} LTI\hspace{1.5mm} system$$

**Can we infer the following?**

A system will behave as causal if:

1.The system impulse response response is causal i.e$$ h[n]=0 \hspace{1.5mm}for\hspace{1.5mm} n<0$$

OR

2.Input signal is a right sided signal$$i.e.\hspace{2mm} x[n]=0 \hspace{1.5mm}for\hspace{1.5mm} n<0$$ to the LTI system irrespective of whether the system is actually causal or not.
Here,although the system is physically the same(i.e. has an impulse response of h[n]) but it ACTS as a system with impulse response x[n] and signal h[n].

Inference 2 is due to commutative property of convolution.

Answer (score 1):

Good question - it is a great example of a case where purely mathematical discussion can't shed a light on the issue.

You are correct about the first statement - causal impulse response of a system is an indication of causal system. The only correction is that it is *if and only if statement*, which also means that any causal system has causal impulse response.

The second statement is incorrect.

Mathematically speaking you're correct - the impulse response and the input are interchangeable inside the convolution integral, but there is more to this than just formalism.

I believe that your confusion arises from the simplified statement of causality: \$causality \Leftrightarrow  \forall x[n]: y[n]=0, \forall n<0\$. This statement is correct, if you remember the underlying assumption, which is: \$x[n]=0, \forall n<0\$. In other words, this simplified statement is correct **only** for right sided inputs and appropriate choice of the origin of \$n\$.

The above can be stated in this way: if for each input that was zero before \$n=0\$ the output is also zero before \$n=0\$, then the system is causal.

The lack of symmetry between \$h[n]\$ and \$x[n]\$ in convolution integral arises from the fact that the impulse response is by definition a response to impulse at \$n=0\$, whereas the input is subject to a time shift - you can move the origin of \$n\$ which affects \$x[n]\$, but does not affect \$y[n]\$ (since the system is time invariant).