# Why a system is causal if the impulse response is zero for \$t<0\$?

Tags: system, systemresponse

I was reading a definition that

> Suppose \$h(t)\$ is the impulse response of any system \$Y\$, then the system is causal if and only if \$h(t)=0\$ for \$\forall t<0\$

I know what a causal system is, but I don't understand it in terms of the impulse response. And I was wondering why is it causal here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of causal signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79824/meaning-of-causal-signal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Causal systems are systems where the output only depend on past/present inputs. The impulse happens at time t=0, so if the output isn't zero prior to t=0 then it depends on a future input.